# bootstrap carousel not working -- images simply stacking

Tags: html, css, carousel

I've been trying to work this out for the past few hours, I've googled and searched through this site for any solution, but any tip or suggestion hasn't been able to rectify the problem.

I'm using CodePen, and simply trying to insert a carousel. When I run the code, the images simply stack on top of each other, with the all slides' text stacking together on the final slide. I can't get a slider or the control buttons/arrows to show up. Any help would be much appreciated. I know the question has been asked before, but as I said, I've tried every solution, even just copying the code and inserting in my information, but with no luck.

```
<style>

.slide1{
background-image: url('http://a.fssta.com/content/dam/fsdigital/fscom/nfl/images/2014/12/09/120914-3-NFL-Packers-Aaron-Rodgers-OB-PI.vresize.1200.675.high.64.jpg');
height: 500px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}

.slide2{
background-image: url('http://www.greenbaypackernation.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/aaron-rodgers-packers.jpg');
height: 500px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}

.slide3{
background-image: url('http://sporrepor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Aaron-Rodgers.jpg');
height: 500px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}

</style>

<body>

<div id="theCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
    <div class="slide1"></div>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Aaron Rodgers</h3>
      <p>Slide 1</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    <div class="slide2"></div>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>ARod</h3>
      <p>Slide 2</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    <div class="slide3"></div>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>AR</h3>
      <p>Slide 3</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
</div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#theCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 2000
   })
```

```css
slide1{
background-image: url('http://a.fssta.com/content/dam/fsdigital/fscom/nfl/images/2014/12/09/120914-3-NFL-Packers-Aaron-Rodgers-OB-PI.vresize.1200.675.high.64.jpg');
height: 500px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}

.slide2{
background-image: url('http://www.greenbaypackernation.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/aaron-rodgers-packers.jpg');
height: 500px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}

.slide3{
background-image: url('http://sporrepor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Aaron-Rodgers.jpg');
height: 500px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>

<div id="theCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
    <div class="slide1"></div>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Aaron Rodgers</h3>
      <p>Slide 1</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    <div class="slide2"></div>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>ARod</h3>
      <p>Slide 2</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    <div class="slide3"></div>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>AR</h3>
      <p>Slide 3</p>
    </div>
    </div>
     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
</div>

<a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
</div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
```

here is your working code you didn't add the bootstrap css

Comment: Wow, thank you. Can't believe I forgot something so simple. I'm going through freecodecamp.com and I thought for sure it said that would be preloaded in Codepen. Apparently not though. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Add Bootstrap CSS File

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


.slide1{
background-image: url('http://a.fssta.com/content/dam/fsdigital/fscom/nfl/images/2014/12/09/120914-3-NFL-Packers-Aaron-Rodgers-OB-PI.vresize.1200.675.high.64.jpg');
height: 500px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}

.slide2{
background-image: url('http://www.greenbaypackernation.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/aaron-rodgers-packers.jpg');
height: 500px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}

.slide3{
background-image: url('http://sporrepor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Aaron-Rodgers.jpg');
height: 500px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b237af1u/